# ReactiveUI + WPF: Binding to 'ItemsSource' not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, reactiveui

I'm unable to bind to the `ItemsSource` property of `ListBox` or `ComboBox` with ReactiveUI and WPF (no problems with UWP). Or to be more precise, the binding seems to work as the `ItemsSource` does get populated but the UI does not show the values properly.

Let me show an example. I created a new WPF project (with VS 2019) and added ReactiveUI 9.16.6 NuGet. My project contains these simple files:

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```cs
<reactiveui:ReactiveWindow 
        x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
        x:TypeArguments="vms:MainViewModel"
        xmlns:vms="clr-namespace:Demo"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:reactiveui="http://reactiveui.net"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="demoList"/>
    </Grid>
</reactiveui:ReactiveWindow>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```cs
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;

namespace Demo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();

            // This works, UI shows "foo" and "bar"
            //demoList.ItemsSource = ViewModel.SomeList;

            this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
            {
                // This doesn't, UI shows two empty items
                this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, viewModel => viewModel.SomeList, view => view.demoList.ItemsSource)
                    .DisposeWith(disposables);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**:

```cs
using ReactiveUI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> SomeList => new List<string> { "foo", "bar" };
    }
}
```

This is the outcome:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsngE.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I also just lodged https://github.com/reactiveui/website/issues/338 since it's not clear from the documentation that is what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default on WPF ReactiveUI will register a ItemTemplate for you, unless
you can override this by specifying a `ItemTemplate`, `ItemTemplateSelector` or `DisplayMemberPath`. See https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/1c45ce3079849c863e99bae3ee315a79ac672add/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/AutoDataTemplateBindingHook.cs#L87 for the source code.

Comment: Thanks. I got what I wanted after adding `ItemTemplate` to my `ListBox` element.

Although I wonder why I need to do it for a simple list of strings. You say that ReactiveUI will register a default `ItemTemplate` for me. Could this default have some problems as the string is not visible on UI?

Comment: This is what I did to get it working:
```c#
        <ListBox x:Name="demoList">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Comment: It's on my to-do list to not have the auto ItemTemplate happen on strings. It's a bit confusing to new users.